# How do I spawn more than one spawnpoint in my scene in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, spawning

I have different enemy AIs and two spawn-points in a scene, so far. The problem I am having is that only one enemy AI spawns, and the other enemy AI won't spawn, in that scene. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemiesSpawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject [] enemy;
    public Transform [] spawnPoints;
    public float spawnTime = 5f;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;

    void Start () 
    {
        //Call the "Spawn" function every 10 seconds.
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
    }

    void Spawn () 
    {
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length); 

        Instantiate(enemy[Random.Range(0, enemy.Length)],
            spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);

        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), 
            1, Random.Range (-spawnValues.z, -spawnValues.z) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your have single enemy assigned to instantiate.

You need an array of enemies to be spawned.

```
public GameObject[] enemy;
```

Then when you instantiate, either do it at random or as you need.

```
Instantiate(enemy[Random.Range(0, enemy.Length)], //will choose from enemy array
            spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position,
            spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
```

In usual case there are two random things to be taken care of. Random enemy and random point to spawn.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44243/discussion-on-answer-by-sp-how-do-i-spawn-more-than-one-spawnpoint-in-my-scene).

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Check chat @Freddy

Comment: What do you mean ?